# Why gcc started checking non-instantiated methods of template classes in v. 7.1?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, gcc, constants

Looks like gcc allowed calling non-const parent methods from const methods of template classes if the latter are not instantiated, but stopped doing this in version 7.1.0. The code below compiles using gcc 6.3.0, but gcc 7.1.0 fails with `error: no matching function for call to 'B<T>::foo() const'`.

```
struct A
{
  int foo () { return 0; }
};

template<typename T>
struct B: public A
{
  int bar() const { return foo(); }
};

int main ()
{
  B<int>();
  return 0;
}
```

I tested different versions here: https://wandbox.org/

If I remove the line `template<typename T>`, both versions fail with `error: passing 'const B' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`

Please explain, why the earlier versions allowed such code, and the recent versions don't?

UPD: All the versions of clang and msvc I found compile the example. So it is wasn't some specific feature of bug in earlier versions of gcc.

UPD: The problem is apparently that earlier versions didn't check non-instantiated methods of template classes. But now they do. Why they did it?

Comment: Most likely a bug fix.

Comment: No, Gcc doesn't allow to do it. `bar` is templated function. Its code is generated when it is used. Did you call `bar` in your code? No. MSVC will give you similar error when you call bar explicitly: `Bar<int> b; b.bar();` try this in Gcc 6.3.

Comment: @rafix07, OK, that's not really calling, I should have formulated the title more correctly. But there is still difference in compiler behavior. Why they did it?

Comment: So what is the new question? Why GCC 7.1.0 tries to instantiate an un-used method?

Comment: @Useless, the question was always the same: why gcc 6.3 compiles it, and 7.1 not.

Comment: It still doesn't instantiate the method. The error texts are different. It does more context checks without instantiations.

Comment: The code is probably ill-formed, no diagnostic required due to http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8.1